# htaccess redirect all 404 to index.php with parameters but don't change address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

What I want to do is redirect all non exist URLS to index.php?q=%URL%, for example:
www.example.com/ggg will redirect to www.example.com/index.php?q=ggg

however, I want the address bar to still show www.example.com/ggg

what I got so far is this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# redirect all requests to non-existing resources to special handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? /index.php?q=$1 [L,NC,R]
```

but it keeps changing the address bar and also I'm not sure it actually works all the time.

any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Actially I want to redirect all error pages, not just 404. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the R flag if You want to rewrite your error pages to index.php.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# redirect all requests to non-existing resources to special handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: got another issue.. when i go to example.com/ggg/ddd it redirects to index.php?q=ggg without the /ddd part... how can i redirect the whole thing? (I want the everything after the "example.com/" will be my parameter)

Comment: @User3720583 see the edit, I changed the regex pattern from ^([^/]+)/? to ^(.+)$ it matches any request.